# How do you create a Hamming encoder/decoder in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, hamming-code

I am trying to create a Hamming encoder/decoder using PHP and I've been trying to wrap my head around calculating the parity bits.

So far, in my script you can input a number, have that number encoded in 8421 code (BCD) or Gray code  and have the encoded number show up on screen. I have also resorted to hard-coding the Gray and BCD code sequences.

The maximum size of the number you can input is 32 bit (4 billion), so if you input a number of that size you will need 40 data bits in your Hamming code.

The basic idea of what I want is: a user inputs a number, that number gets converted into Gray Code/8421 and then into Hamming code. Afterwards the user has the option to decode the number.

The issue that I'm having is that I cannot seem to figure out an algorithm that will dynamically generate parity bits and calculate them as needed. I have included the relevant code below.

Thank you!

**encode.php**

```
 session_start();


if ( !isset($_POST['num_to_convert']) || !is_numeric($_POST['num_to_convert']) ){

    $_SESSION['redirect']=1;
    header ('Location: form.php');

}
else


    {   


        $method=$_POST['metoda'];
        $number=$_POST['num_to_convert'];
        $string="$_POST[num_to_convert]";
        $to_convert=str_split($string);

        $encoded_value='';

        // Pentru metoda 8421

        if($method=='8421')
            {

            foreach($to_convert as $value)

            {
                switch($value){

                    case 0: 
                        $encoded_value.="0000";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        $encoded_value.="0001";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $encoded_value.="0010";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $encoded_value.="0011";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $encoded_value.="0100";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $encoded_value.="0101";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $encoded_value.="0110";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        $encoded_value.="0111";
                        break;  
                    case 8:
                        $encoded_value.="1000";
                        break;  
                    case 9:
                        $encoded_value.="1001";
                        break;  
                    }
                }
                }


            // Pentru metoda Gray

            if($method=='Gray')
            {

            foreach($to_convert as $value)
            {
                switch($value){

                    case 0:
                        $encoded_value.="0000";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        $encoded_value.="0001";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $encoded_value.="0010";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $encoded_value.="0011";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $encoded_value.="0110";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $encoded_value.="0111";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $encoded_value.="0101";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        $encoded_value.="0100";
                        break;  
                    case 8:
                        $encoded_value.="1100";
                        break;  
                    case 9:
                        $encoded_value.="1101";
                        break;  
                    }
                }
            }




            $_SESSION['num_to_convert']=$_POST['num_to_convert'];
            $_SESSION['encoded_value']=$encoded_value;
            $_SESSION['method']=$method;





        header('Location: form.php');

    }
```

**form.php** is just the input and output script, nothing to be seen there.

Comment: The pseudo code at the bottom of [this](http://diga.me.uk/Gray.html) may help you in your efforts.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It has indeed given me a bit more insight.